# Change icon on browser's bookmark while website's tab is closed?

Tags: browser, cross-browser

It's quite simple to change the favicon.ico on the browser's tab. If the tab corresponding to our site/application is not the selected one, this can draw the attention of users and lead them to find out what's new on them.

But I was wondering if it's possible to dynamically change the icon on bookmark items, even when our website's tab is not open.

Anybody knows how can this be accomplished? Should be done by means of a browser's plugin?

Comment: The bookmark icon is cached locally and as long as you don't access that bookmark's url, the icon will not be changed. At least for desktop bookmarks.